# Turning this JS Code for Text Animation from "on click" to automatic when HTML page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate

I'm trying to implement this text animation (N.10 from https://speckyboy.com/css-javascript-text-animation-snippets/)

so I copied the HTML and the CSS code worked fine. I got rid of the reload button because that needs to go away. I know that I am supposed to copy the js script code into the head section for it to load automatically, however... I don't know how to "rewrite" it so it stops being a click action...and just becomes a "normal" function.

```
$(function() {
  $('.intro').addClass('go');

  $('.reload').click(function() {
    $('.intro').removeClass('go').delay(200).queue(function(next) {
      $('.intro').addClass('go');
      next();
    });

  });
})
```

(I got this from the link obviously)
I'll make sure to use the ".onload" to get it to run when page is loaded. it's probably a very easy thing to do but got kind of confused...

I'd be very grateful for the help! Thank you :)

Comment: See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ You are almost there.

Answer (score 0):

It's the part that is **not**

```
$(selector).click(function() {});
```

In your case, **delete** the framed block

```
$(function() {
  $('.intro').addClass('go');
```

> ```
>   $('.reload').click(function() {
>     $('.intro').removeClass('go').delay(200).queue(function(next) {
>       $('.intro').addClass('go');
>       next();
>     });    
>   });
> ```

```
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you removed the reload button, but that didn't reflect in your js code.

```
$(function() {   $('.intro').addClass('go');   $('.intro').removeClass('go').delay(200) .queue(function(next) {       $('.intro').addClass('go'); next();     }); })
```

What i did here was to remove the `click` event added to the non existing *reload* button. But you will need to tweak the code to remove the `go` class and cause the delay. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

remove it from on click on add it to document.ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.intro').addClass('go');
   $('.intro').removeClass('go').delay(200).queue(function(next) {
      $('.intro').addClass('go');
      next();
    });

  });
```